# Clarification for "Accessing Subscripts of Optional Type" in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, option-type

Can someone explain why optional chaining is done on a non-optional subarray. I am confused by the explanation given by Apple's Swift documentation:

> If a subscript returns a value of optional type—such as the key subscript of Swift’s Dictionary type—place a question mark after the subscript’s closing bracket to chain on its optional return value:

Documentation Example:

```
var testScores = ["Dave": [86, 82, 84], "Bev": [79, 94, 81]]
testScores["Dave"]?[0] = 91
testScores["Bev"]?[0]++
testScores["Brian"]?[0] = 72
// the "Dave" array is now [91, 82, 84] and the "Bev" array is now [80, 94, 81]
```

Shouldn't the declaration be:

```
var testScores:[String:Array<Int>?] = ["Dave": [86, 82, 84], "Bev": [79, 94, 81]]
```

Here is the Apple Swift Documentation section on [Accessing Subscripts of Optional Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion here is that the dictionary `testScores` is non-optional, but the value `testScores["Dave"]` is optional.  The reason is that any time you ask for a value from a dictionary, it might be there...or it might not.  Returning from a dictionary is an inherently optional operation.  Consider if you had said, `testScores["Fred"]`--this would have returned `nil`.  Since it is possible to return an object, or possible to return `nil`, subscripting a `Dictionary` of `Array`s returns an optional `Array`.  The return type (`[Int]?`), therefore, differs from the value type (`[Int]`).

The second example you give is subtly different.  Rather than the return type being optional, in your second example, the element *itself* is optional.  This means that you could have something like this:

```
let array1 = [0, 1, 2]
let array2: [Int]? = nil
let dict = ["Fred": array1, "Wilma": array2] // [String: [Int]?]
```

In that case, you actually have *two layers* of optionals (an optional optional array of ints, `[Int]??`, and would need to access an element like this:

```
let x = dict["Fred"]??[0]
```

Comment: What the hell? Nowhere in Apple's Swift documentation does it talk about this. lol. But you are right. I confirmed this on a xcode playground. I come from C++ programming background, and this optional thing is quiet new to me. I would have never guessed it returned an optional. Thank you for this!

Comment: No worries!  My background is in C++ also, but the more that I work in Swift, the more I wish optionals were a standard part of C++--they are incredibly useful.  And I say "standard" because they actually *do* exist as an [experimental](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) feature.

Comment: Btw, does this also apply for multidimensional arrays, not just dictionaries?

Comment: @WalterM And by the way, if this answered your question, please consider checking accepting it by checking the tick mark beneath the counter.  :-)

Comment: There you go :). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Arrays are actually a bit different--they don't return an optional, but rather give you an out-of-bounds error if you ask for something outside the array.  A bit more like a `std::vector` in C++.  This *may* be returning something called an implicitly unwrapped optional (you've seen this if you've seen the exclamation point syntax), but I'm not 100% sure.